# Convert Datetime to String in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I am calling one of the column dateadded in the datalist like:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded") %>'></asp:Label>
```

On display it shows 24/04/2012 12:07:52 and i want to display : April 2012,

Can any one provide any assistance on how to get this display
Thanks
updated:

I trid this with no success:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded").ToString("yyyyMM") %>'></asp:Label>
```

updated 2 [working]:

```
'<%# Eval("DateAdded" ,"{0:MMMM yyyy}") %>'>
```

Comment: there are many examples if you google it.

Comment: Have a look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: yeh but all the example are codebehind ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. Something like this should work:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded", "{0:MMMM yyyy}") %>'
```

The problem with your example is the `Eval` function returns type `object`, so it doesn't know how to apply the format. The `Eval` function overload (above) accepts a format and can figure all of that out behind-the-scenes, but you can also work around this by casting or converting the value to `DateTime`:

```
Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("DateAdded")).ToString("MMMM yyyy") %>'
```

Comment: That will display as `201204` he wants `April 2012`

Comment: @Jeff: Fixed to display full month name and four-digit year.

Comment: @MrA: I updated my answer to display the full month and four digit year, e.g. `April 2012`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt");
```